# Properly Importing a Python Class in Autokey

Tags: python, ubuntu, autokey

I have a class of static methods that I wrote as a supplement to the [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) API. I would like to include these in my scripts that I write in the autokey editor, but I've not been able to quite figure it out yet as my experience with python is still limited.

Where do I put my class-name.py file to be able to import it into autokey?

Comment: Can you alter the import path of autokey?

Comment: I can use the import directive in the scripts if that's what you mean.

Comment: If it's plain python, we should be able to append some path - where you place class-name.py - to `sys.path`, then we can import modules found in that path.

Comment: It's plain python. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You may alter the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. This is the related document: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to store all the python modules you're going to use with autokey under the same folder and select that folder as the `User Module Folder` in `Preferences -> Script Engine`.

For example, in the image below I've set `~/autokey` as the directory where my helper modules are available:

[image: User Module Folder]

Note: The advice in the comments regarding changing `PYTHONPATH`/`sys.path` are also correct. The `User Module Folder` configuration basically appends the folder you select to `sys.path` to make the user modules available to your autokey scripts.

Comment: of some reasons this solution did not work for me at home. as a workaround i using [rewrite-all.py](https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux/blob/master/run-run-lintalistAHK-rewrite-all.py)